# VBA Code will not rename sheet

Tags: vba, excel

It was working perfectly until I added a message box to it and since then the code will simply not rename the sheet and uses the "copied from  (SHEET86)" sheets name instead.

I have 12 sets of the same code activated by their own button and they all work fine but not the first one. I even copied one piece of code from a working macro and changed the cell references but it will simply not rename the sheet as is in the code.

I have copied the macros here-under so you can see they are identical in every respect. I have checked and re-checked the buttons have the correct macro assigned to no avail so wondering if anyone else has experienced this before or if I should be looking elsewhere?

```
Sub copySht1()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim mySheetname As String
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheet74.Range("D6")

    For p = 1 To 1      
        mySheetname = MyRange.Text
        Sheet86.Copy After:=Sheet84
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Schedule - " & mySheetname
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Schedule - " & mySheetname
    Next p
    MsgBox "Schedule for aircraft" & Cells(6, "D") & " Created"
End Sub


Sub copySht2()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim mySheetname As String
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheet74.Range("E6")

    For p = 1 To 1 
        mySheetname = MyRange.Text
        Sheet86.Copy After:=Sheet84
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Schedule - " & mySheetname
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Schedule - " & mySheetname
    Next p
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `for p=1 to 1` and `next p` from both subs.

Comment: I suggest to: (1) use `Option Explicit` ([see how](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit)) (2) Remove `On Error Resume Next` and run your code. (3) [Edit] Your question and tell us **where** you get an error and **what** the error message is. I think this is the best way to see where your issue is.

Comment: Hi Peh and thanks for taking the time to reply. I have removed the on error Resume next bit, added the Option Explicit and whilst I was reading through that I saw a post about error handling so plugged that in and am receiving an error that the name is already taken. Without that error handling am receiving the X 400 message which I am currently researching. The strange this is that all the other macros are using the same sheet to copy from and are successfully running and completing fine

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `Sheet86` or `Sheet84` are not declared variables.

First: use `Sheets("Sheet86")`

Second: always use `Option Explicit` to avoid coming back to us with such a trivial error.

PS: I add Peh's suggestion: on error resume next is only for when you know what may cause an error and you know it can be resumed.

Comment: I recommend always using `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets`. The `Sheets` collection can contain Chart or Worksheet objects. The `Worksheets` collection contain only Worksheet objects. So never use `Sheets` unless you need to include Charts etc.

Comment: @Peh Thanks for this information, I didn't know that

Comment: `Sheet74`, `Sheet84` and `Sheet86` are almost certainly the `CodeName` of three different sheets, and it is therefore probably quite valid for them to be used as they are.  (But there **is** a possibility that those sheets have been deleted.  `Option Explicit` will certainly detect it if they have been.)

Answer (score 0):

I could be stoned for such a solution, but can you try:

```
Sub copySht1()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim mySheetname As String
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheet74.Range("D6")

        mySheetname = MyRange.Text
        Sheet86.Copy After:=Sheet84
        Sheet86.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Schedule - " & mySheetname
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Schedule - " & mySheetname

    MsgBox "Schedule for aircraft" & Cells(6, "D") & " Created"
End Sub
```

Just to check whether it would work :)

Comment: Hi Vityata and thanks for the response. No change to the results. She remains obstinate...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the code. Please double check if you are executing copySht1() twice or if the sheet name("Schedule - " & mySheetname) already exists. Only in these cases it will take the "Sheet86(2)" (or) "Copied from (Sheets86)" since you used 'On Error Resume Next' it is not throwing actual error message.

Comment: Thank you Ram for your reply. I have checked and that name is not in use anywhere else. The other 11 macros all use the same sheet to copy from and the only difference is really the &mySheetname which is derived from cell "D6". the message that is generated also generates the correct file name, it just wont rename that sheet..

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all for your advice on my problem. Being in aviation and not in coding I am pretty new to learning VBA so all your comments have me searching and finding out more about it.
The issue is now resolved and what I did was to delete sheet 86 and re-create it from scratch. I then re-saved the workbook under a new name, shut down Excel, re-opened and the code is now working as it is supposed to. I can only guess at the real issue which must have been to do with sheet 86.
Once again, many thanks for taking time to provide feedback ..
Best regards